# I have issue when validating XSD file with xml file

Tags: xml, xsd

I have downloaded two file form poin2 to listing property and i have to some functionality using that but before that i have done validation using http://xsdvalidation.utilities-online.info/ and when click validate xml against XSD then i got error like:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration
>   of element 'ListingDataFeed'.

What should be the cause of this error?

**Update** : 
XSD File : http://www.repeatproperty.com/point2xsd.xsd 
XML File : http://www.repeatproperty.com/listingdatafeed.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple: there's an element "ListingDataFeed" in your XML for which no declaration can be found in the schema, either locally to some complex type that was being evaluated or in the schema root. It means the XML is not valid for that schema.

By the way, can you change the title of the question to "I have an issue when validating an XML file with XSD"? The word "comparing" is confusing in this context.

EDIT: Oh, and if you're at liberty to do so, post the schema and XML file. If they're very long, try to limit it to relevant extracts. It may not be possible if they contain sensitive info, though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and i have put link of XSD and xml file both in my question.

Comment: It seems the XML file is not valid against the schema. Element ListingDataFeed is defined as allowed to contain a Listings element, which in turn can contain a Listing element. The XML also has elements such as PublishDate and DocumentationUrl under its root, which the schema wouldn't allow. Either correct the XML or alter the schema. I also advise you to find a more helpful tool than an online validator. Maybe check some Notepad++ plugins or find a free XML editor.